# Problemas al enviar elementos a mi vista

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

Estoy teniendo problemas al enviar colecciones a mi vista blade. en mi controller tengo implementada la función index de esta forma:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $productos = Producto::latest()
                    ->take(5)
                    ->get();

        $clientes = Clientes::latest()
            ->take(5)
            ->get();

        $proveedores = Proveedor::latest()
            ->take(5)
            ->get();


        $facturas = Factura::latest()
                    ->take(5)
                    ->get();

        $facturas_canceladas = Factura::latest()
            ->take(5)
            ->get();

        //DETERMINAR LOS PRODUCTOS MAS SOLICITADOS

        $ventas = Producto::withCount('ventasProductos')
                            ->orderBy('ventas_productos_count', 'desc')
                            ->take(5)
                            ->get();

        return view('home')->with('productos', $productos)->with('facturas_canceladas', $facturas_canceladas)
                           ->with('facturas', $facturas)->with('ventas', $ventas)->with('clientes', $clientes)
                           ->with('proveedores', $proveedores);
```

pero me lanza este error:

```
Undefined variable: ventas (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\productos_ventas2\resources\views\home.blade.php)
```

Revise en mi vista y la variable ventas esta bien puesta. Si elimino esta variable me arrastra el error a la otra variable que le sigue que es clientes etc.

Comment: Muy raro, sin embargo no es necesario todos esos with, puedes hacerlo con compact y se usa menos código y se lee más fácil: `return view('home', compact('productos, 'facturas_canceladas', 'facturas', 'ventas', 'clientes', 'proveedores'));`

Comment: si muy extraño lo acabo de probar con el compact y lo mismo

Comment: Agrega el código de la vista.

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto, explico de que se trataba el error:

En mi ruta tenia tenia implementada la siguiente ruta:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('home');
    });
```

Esta no tiraba contra ninguna controller y ese era el problema. Entonces definí bien la ruta y listo:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Comment: Si usas una versión reciente de Laravel, simplemente puedes hacer: `Route::view('/', 'home');`